# Cannot delete the correct post using MongoDB Atlas with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongodb-atlas

I'm building a web app using MongoDB Atlas with Next.js

The app should have full CRUD to posts, so far creating and updating posts are working fine.

But I couldn't make the app delete the correct post...

Here is my route for deletion:

```
export const DELETE = async (request, { params }) => {
  console.log("params from single post api (delete)", params);
  try {
    await connectToDB();
    await Post.findOneAndDelete(params.id);
    return new Response("Post deleted successfully", { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response("Failed to delete the post", { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

Console has logged the id of the post that I want to delete

> params from single post api (delete) { id: '64b10e1f0535aa38a6f4eac9' }

But when I looked at the DB after hitting delete btn, the post is still there.

Instead, another post has been deleted. I wonder why...

I've used both `findOneAndDelete()` and `findOneAndRemove()`, didn't see the difference.

Here is the full code:
https://github.com/gongtzuuuu/meloverse/blob/main/app/api/post/%5Bid%5D/route.js

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The findOneAndDelete method expects a query object as its parameter, not just the ID of the post. In your code, you're passing params.id directly to findOneAndDelete.

```js
    const query = { _id: ObjectId(params.id) }
         //or
    const query = { _id: params.id } // if you are sure that id is a string.
    await Post.findOneAndDelete(query)
```